# How to change the color of a class based on data your recieving?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, pokeapi

Ok so I am working on a Random Pokémon Generator and every time the user clicks the generate button it picks a random number between 1-905(Number of Pokémon in National Dex). I am able to show the image, name/id, and typing of the Pokémon that is generated. What im stuck on is how to change the color of the background of the container/class that the Pokémon is displayed in based on the typing of said Pokémon. Say the Pokémon's typing is grass I would want the background to be a green color.
I really don't know where to start to even do this.

I am using **PokeApi**

```
const pokemongenerated = document.getElementById('pokemongenerated');

const fetchPokemon = () => {
const array = [];
const randomID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 906) + 1;


    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${randomID}`;
    array.push(fetch(url).then((res) => res.json()));

Promise.all(array).then((results) => {
     const pokemon = results.map((data) => ({
        name: data.name,
        image: data.sprites['front_default'],
        type: data.types.map((type) => type.type.name).join(', '),
        id: data.id,
        
       

    }));
    displayPokemon(pokemon);
  });
 };
const displayPokemon = (pokemon) => {
console.log(pokemon);
const pokemonHTMLString = pokemon
    .map(
        (pokemon) => `
    <ul class="card">
        <img class="card-image" src="${pokemon.image}"/>
        <h2 class="card-name"> ${pokemon.id}. ${pokemon.name}</h2>
        <p class="card-type">Type: ${pokemon.type}</p>

    </ul>
`
    )
    .join('');

pokemonGenerated.innerHTML = pokemonHTMLString;
};

fetchPokemon();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Create a typeCss on object
2.Make css styles for all type

```js
const pokemongenerated = document.getElementById('pokemongenerated');

const fetchPokemon = () => {
const array = [];
const randomID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 906) + 1;


    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${randomID}`;
    array.push(fetch(url).then((res) => res.json()));

Promise.all(array).then((results) => {
     const pokemon = results.map((data) => ({
        name: data.name,
        image: data.sprites['front_default'],
        type: data.types.map((type) => type.type.name).join(', '),
        typeCss: data.types.map((type)=>type.type.name).join('--'),
        id: data.id,
        
       

    }));
    displayPokemon(pokemon);
  });
 };
const displayPokemon = (pokemon) => {
console.log(pokemon);
const pokemonHTMLString = pokemon
    .map(
        (pokemon) => `
    <ul class="card pokemon-type type-${pokemon.typeCss}">
        <img class="card-image" src="${pokemon.image}"/>
        <h2 class="card-name"> ${pokemon.id}. ${pokemon.name}</h2>
        <p class="card-type">Type: ${pokemon.type}</p>

    </ul>
`
    )
    .join('');

document.querySelector('#pokemonGenerated').innerHTML = pokemonHTMLString;
};

fetchPokemon();
```

```css
.pokemon-type[class*="water"]{
background:blue;
}
.pokemon-type[class*="grass"]{
background:green;
}

//so on
```

```html
<div id="pokemonGenerated"></div>
```

Comment: This seemed to work wonderfully! For the Pokémon that have multiple types the second typing that is pulled is the color of the background, any suggestions on how I can deal with multi typing? I just need a way to define that in CSS.

Comment: The class will look like `type-bug--flying` and you can specify for each type a color, or combined. Problem is the last class defined in .css file is the one that will show. Ex `.pokemon-type[class*="flying"] { background:red}` `.pokemon-type[class*="bug"] {background:blue}` and the pokemon has type `bug, flying` it will show the color of `bug` because is the last one, if you want you can do `.pokemon-type[class*="bug--flying"] { background:purple}` to do specifically for this.